# Image of $f$ in $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ out of bounds for intervals?

Tags: functions, special-functions

Edit 1. This all being worked on with the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$

Given a function $f(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor$ (Floor function). Find the image of B, $f^{-1}(B)$ if $B = [0,1)$

For easier cases such as $B=\{0,1\}$, it's obvious that the image of B would be $f^{-1}(B) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}\colon 0\le x < 2\}$.  However, I can't seem to figure out the one with a interval.

What I'm confused about is that, for example, $0.5$ doesn't have a solution in $f(x)$. Am I supposed to write that the image of $B$ does not exist in such case?

Edit 1 Here's a badly drawn image illustrating how I see this, the $2.5$ value cannot be traced back to A, because of the function transforming every number to an integer. [image]

Comment: Here is $\lfloor x\rfloor=x-[x]$??

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What I'm working with is for example $f(1.2325) = 1, f(1.99999) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(2.0000000001) = 2$. As in, only the integer part of the number.

Comment: Then the notation is $f(x)=[x]$ I think

Comment: See I am giving the answer for both $[x]$ & $x-[x]$ you take the idea

Comment: @user152715 No, the notation $\lfloor x \rfloor$ was correct... [See Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) for example. And the LaTeX commands for $\lfloor x \rfloor$ are `\lfloor x \rfloor`... I'm not sure what you're confused about.

Comment: Yeah I have seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Notation both notations are used. Anyway I have given both the answers I think it will be usefull.

Comment: Added an image to explain what I'm confused about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Normally the for $f(x)=[x]$ we have $f(x)$ is the greatest integer value of x. s.t $f(1.5)=1$ & $f(-1.5)=2$. So the inverse image $f^{-1}(B)=[0,1)$.

**Some clarification for the asker**

If $B=[x,x+1)$ where $x\ge 0$ then $f^{-1}B=x$ if  $B=[x,x+1)$ where $x< 0$ then $f^{-1}B=x$.
Now is it clear to you.

Again if you take $f(x)=x-[x]$ then $f^{-1}(B)=\Bbb R$

Comment: I have edited. Just a minute.

Comment: Thing is, say $B = [-1,2)$ That would mean I couldn't specify the image of $B$ because, i.e. $-1.4$, which is defined in B, cannot have an $x$ value so that $f(x) = -1.4$. This is what I'm confused about.

Comment: See there should not be any confusion, if you understand the definition clearly.

Comment: I'll draw an image to illustrate what I mean, one moment.

Comment: Now see this picture

Comment: The image you added can be used to explain what I'm trying to understand as well. If I get that $B$ IS defined for $[-3,4)$, that means $y=2.5$ is defined as well, right? But in your graph $y=2.5$ does NOT have a solution; and therefore I can't write the image of $B$ because it can take on values which does NOT have $x$ solutions.

Comment: Yes if $B=(1,2)$ say, then $f^{-1}(B)=\phi$. What the problem in it??!